# how to pass a file path to PdfReader of iText

Tags: java, android, itext

im using iText to get content of a pdf like this :

```
try {
            String parsedText="";
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "test.pdf");
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(String.valueOf(file));
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
                parsedText   = parsedText+ PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i+1).trim()+"\n"; //Extracting the content from the different pages
            }
            
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            Log.d("heh", String.valueOf(e));

        }
```

but it returns the error:

```
/data/user/0/com.clementine.story_project/files/test.pdf not found as file or resource.
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that file exists? How is that file getting into that location?

Answer (score 0):

PdfReader doesn't accept file object, but it accept InputStream. So you can use the below code

```
 Path path = file.toPath();
 if(Files.exists(path)) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Files.newInputStream(path));
   //other operations
 }
```

Also, added a file exists condition before calling the stream.